# Margin when a div takes many lines

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this, with the div `#a` always of width 50px:

```css
#a { width: 50px; display: inline-block; }
#b { display: inline-block; margin-left: 50px; }
#c { margin-left: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
10:30
</div>
<div id="b">
Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
</div>
<div id="c">
Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
</div>
```

The desired rendering is (solution A):

```
10:30    Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
         Title Title Title Title ...
         Description Description Description Description 
         Description Description ...
```

and, for another part of the website (solution B):

```
10:30    Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
Title Title Title Title ...
Description Description Description Description 
Description Description ...
```

but not

```
10:30    
         Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
         Title Title Title Title ...
```

**How to solve this layout issue?** (with the simplest CSS rules possible, i.e. no flexbox, etc.)

Comment: Wrap a and b, let them float and set them `display: block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution A

```css
#a { width: 50px; float:left; }
#b, #c { margin-left: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
10:30
</div>
<div id="b">
Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
</div>
<div id="c">
Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
</div>
```

---

Solution B

```css
#a { width: 50px; display: inline-block; }
#b { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
10:30
</div>
<div id="b">
Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
</div>
<div id="c">
Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this perfect solution, showing both `float: left` (A) and `display: inline` (B).

Answer (score 3):

```css
#a {float:left; width: 50px; }
#b, #c { margin-left: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
  10:30
</div>
<div id="b">
  Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title   Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title   Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
</div>
<div id="c">
  Description Description Description Description Description Description   Description Description Description Description Description Description   Description Description
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```css
#a{
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    width: 50px;
}
.wrap{
 padding-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div id="a">
  10:30
 </div>
 <div id="b">
  Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
 </div> 
 <div id="c">
  Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
 </div>
</div>
```

You can do it in many ways, here is a my solution. I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#someWrapper {width: 100%; clear: both;}
#a { width: 50px; display: block; float: left;}
#b { width: 300px; float: left;}
#c { margin-left: 50px; display: block; float: left; }
```

```html
<div id="someWrapper">
    <div id="a">
    10:30
    </div>
    <div id="b">
    Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c">
    Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description
    </div>
```